# Popover page not loading Ionic 3

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

My problem is as follows. I added a popover page and added the PopoverController to the page where it should be opened. When I click the button that should open the popover only the arrow of the popover is shown. The content is not loading. Also in the log it won't show "ionViewDidLoad RaidUsersModalPage".
I inspected the element in browser and the popover-content div is empty, like below.

```
<div class="popover-wrapper" style="opacity: 1;">
    <div class="popover-arrow" style="top: 209.1px; left: 88.25px;"></div>
    <div class="popover-content" style="top: 218.1px; left: 2px; transform-origin: left top 0px;">
        <div class="popover-viewport">
            <div nav-viewport=""></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The function I'm using is as follows:

```
presentRaidusersPopover(myEvent) {
    let popover = this.popoverCtrl.create(this.raidUsersModalPage);
    popover.present({
      ev: myEvent
    });
}
```

In the page HTML I'm opening function as follows:

```
<ion-col col-6>             
    <button ion-button icon-start small color="light" (click)="presentRaidusersPopover($event)">
        <ion-icon name="people"></ion-icon>
    {{ qOptedIn }}
    </button>
</ion-col>
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: can you provide an example on stackblizz?

Comment: what is `this.raidUsersModalPage` ?

Comment: Its like the following

`import { RaidUsersModalPage } from '../raid-users-modal/raid-users-modal';

export class RaidInfoPage {
 raidUsersModalPage: RaidUsersModalPage;
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Suraj Rao I found my mistake. I feel kinda stupid for this one.

I declared my page like this:

```
raidUsersModalPage: RaidUsersModalPage;
```

Instead of this:

```
raidUsersModalPage = RaidUsersModalPage;
```

Strange that I did not get any error at all, but it's working great right now!

Comment: You wont get an error because the first syntax sets the type. You are just passing `undefined` to popover